# Laravel default CREATED_AT and UPDATED_AT column names don't change

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a model `Brand` with a migration and I want to change the default timestamps' names to `brandCreatedAt` and `brandUpdatedAt`

I tried overriding the constants like below and migrating again but the table is still created with default timestamps name like `created_at` and `updated_at`

```php
const CREATED_AT = 'brandCreatedAt';
const UPDATED_AT = 'brandUpdatedAt';
```

Migration -

```php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('brands', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('brandName')->nullable();
            $table->string('brandIsActive')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Then I tried defining `protected $table = 'brands';` but the issue remains. Then tried clearing cache with both artisan command and defining a route but no success. Maybe this is a small issue but I tried hours trying to find what's the issue but still I couldn't find it. TIA!

Comment: If you're still using `$table->timestamps()` in the migration, that will create `created_at` and `updated_at`; that code is independent of the model. You'll likely need to remove `$table->timestamps()` from your migration, and manually add `$table->timestamp('brandCreatedAt')` and `$table->timestamp('brandUpdatedAt')` (you didn't include your migration, so this comment is an assumption)

Comment: @TimLewis added migration code.

Comment: As Tim said, the models are never "related" to the database (migrations), you must specify everything you want to or need to in a migration, the migration does not care what the model has on it. But, one recommendation, use `snake_case` instead of `camelCase`, I do not know if you model has every column as `camelCase` or `snake_case`, but I would recommend `snake_case` as that is the default from the framework. Never mix both cases

Comment: @matiaslauriti I 100% agree with your comment re: cases; definitely best not to mix. 1 problem, saying *"the models are **never** related to the database (migrations)"*  is _mostly_ accurate, but not "never". There are migration methods that _do_ use models though, like [`foreignIdFor(Model)`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-method-foreignIdFor). Would be interesting if there was a method `timestampsFor(Model)` that used the model-level column name overrides, but alas.

Comment: @TimLewis absolutely true! I think that would be a nice addition to the core 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following what [@Tim Lewis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3965631/tim-lewis) said, you should have files like these:

#### Model

```php
class Brand extends Model
{
    // ...

    public const CREATED_AT = 'brandCreatedAt';
    public const UPDATED_AT = 'brandUpdatedAt';

    // ...
}
```

#### Migration

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('brands', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('brandName')->nullable();
        $table->string('brandIsActive')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp(Brand::CREATED_AT);
        $table->timestamp(Brand::UPDATED_AT);
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't forget `use App\Models\Brand;` at the top of this migration. otherwise, this is 